# catalogrule_apply_all and other Magento core jobs have no time and no model

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I have a Magento 1.9.2.1 store where the `n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:list` looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+----+
| Job                                     | Model                                    | m   | h                                                             | D  | M  | WD |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+----+
| Webshopapps_Wsalogger                   |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| adjcartalert_create                     |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| adjcartalert_stat                       |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| aggregate_sales_report_coupons_data     |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| aggregate_sales_report_invoiced_data    |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| aggregate_sales_report_order_data       |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| aggregate_sales_report_refunded_data    |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| aggregate_sales_report_shipment_data    |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| aggregate_sales_report_tax_data         |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| aoescheduler_heartbeat                  | aoe_scheduler/task_heartbeat::run        | */5 | *                                                             | *  | *  | *  |
| aoescheduler_testtask                   |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| captcha_delete_expired_images           |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| captcha_delete_old_attempts             |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| catalog_product_alert                   | productalert/observer::process           | 0   | 0                                                             | *  | *  | *  |
| catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| catalogrule_apply_all                   |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| core_clean_cache                        | core/observer::cleanCache                | 30  | 2                                                             | *  | *  | *  |
| core_email_queue_clean_up               | core/email_queue::cleanQueue             | 0   | 0                                                             | *  | *  | *  |
| core_email_queue_send_all               |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| currency_rates_update                   |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| find_feed_file_send                     |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| flexinvoice                             | flexinvoice/observer::resetLastValue     | 0   | 0                                                             | 1  | 1  | *  |
| log_clean                               | log/cron::logClean                       | 0   | 23                                                            | *  | *  | *  |
| mailup_mailupsync                       |                                          | 0   | 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 | *  | *  | *  |
| newsletter_send_all                     |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| paypal_fetch_settlement_reports         |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| persistent_clear_expired                | persistent/observer::clearExpiredCronJob | 0   | 0                                                             | *  | *  | *  |
| rw_feeds_queue                          |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| rw_feeds_schedule                       |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| sales_clean_quotes                      |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| simplegoogleshopping_generate           |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| sitemap_generate                        |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
| system_backup                           |                                          |     |                                                               |    |    |    |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+----+
```

As you can see, many critical Magento jobs have no Model and no execution time. I need to restore `catalogrule_apply_all` to their original scheduled time.

I already check `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml`: it has the standard

```
        <catalogrule_apply_all>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate</model>
            </run>
        </catalogrule_apply_all>
```

This store also has [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) installed: my task is to remove Aoe and switch the handling back to Magento built-in cron. I already tried to disable `catalogrule_apply_all` from Aoe_Scheduler + disable it via .xml, but neither had any effect.

So how can I get back the original planning execution for `catalogrule_apply_all` and other Magento cron jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did that by simply disabling the Aoe_Scheduler extension from file "app/etc/modules/Aoe_Scheduler.xml" setting the "active" XML node text to "false" and than flushed the cache from the back-end and the cron system just started functioning normally. That happened on Magento 1.9.3.1

Comment: I highly recommend upgrading to 1.9.3.2. The upgrade is low-risk and fixes a high-risk security issue.